# Node.js get object key value output

Tags: node.js, api-design

I've been trying to output the name value of this object called `Tea`. How can I do that?

```js
//POST '/tea'

const newTea = (req, res, next) => {
  const newTea = new Tea({
    name: req.body.name,
    image: req.body.image, // placeholder for now
    description: req.body.description,
    keywords: req.body.keywords,
    origin: req.body.origin,
    brew_time: req.body.brew_time,
    temperature: req.body.temperature,
  });
  return res.json(newTea);
};
```

Currently, when I provide values and check on Postman, it gives the JSON output as follows:

```json
{
  "_id": "6059132c3967b75d13e53736",
  "comments": []
}
```

Why is this happening?

also newTea is defined in a models.ts file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose

// tea schema
const TeaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    image: String,
    description: String,
    keywords: String,
    origin: String,
    brew_time: Number,
    temperature: Number,
    comments: [{ text: String, date: {type:String, default: new Date()} }]
});

const Tea = mongoose.model('Tea', TeaSchema); //convert to model named Tea
module.exports = Tea; //export for controller use
```

Comment: You are using new Tea as if Tea is a Class. Do you have the Tea class code or docs to reference?

Comment: yes there is a model.js file where it is defined. const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose

// tea schema
const TeaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    image: String,
    description: String,
    keywords: String,
    origin: String,
    brew_time: Number,
    temperature: Number,
    comments: [{ text: String, date: {type:String, default: new Date()} }]
});

const Tea = mongoose.model('Tea', TeaSchema); //convert to model named Tea
module.exports = Tea; //export for controller use

Comment: It's been a while since I have used Mongoose. When you instantiate a new class shouldn't you save it? I am not sure why you are returning the raw object back express response. What are you expecting to return to express?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `new` to create objects, `new` is used for instantiating a Class.

[JavaScript new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)
[JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

To make an object it is simpler, you simply structure as you would like. For example:

```js
const newTea = (req, res, next) => {
  const tea = {
    name:req.body.name,
    image: req.body.image, // placeholder for now
    description: req.body.description,
    keywords: req.body.keywords,
    origin: req.body.origin,
    brew_time: req.body.brew_time,
    temperature: req.body.temperature,
  };

  return res.json(newTea); 
}
```